# Oracle SQL Inserting multiple rows into a table while referencing 2 FK

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm trying to insert values id_team_FK and id_location_FK which both come from the same table.
For example id_team_FK = 4 and id_location_FK = 150. The problem is, id_team_FK must be a randomly chosen value from team_table ( this works) and I need to know the exact number ( for example 4 ) to realize which id_location_FK is assigned to it ( for example 150 ). How do I make it work ?

```
   insert into test (PK, id_team_FK,id_location_FK)
values (1,
-- Selects random number from table
(select * from  (id_team_FK from team_table  order by dbms_random.random) where rownum=1),
-- needs to know the value of id_team_FK to know what select...
(select * from ( select id_location_FK from team_table) where team_table.id_team_FK = id_team_FK));
```

Comment: If you select both the columns from the same table, then just select them with one `select`. Is there one-to-many relationship between `id_team_FK` and `id_location_FK`?

Comment: @astentx it is a one to one relationship

Comment: Then why not `insert into test select * from (select 1 as id, id_team_fk, id_lication_fk from team_table order by dbms_random.random()) where rownum = 1)`?

Comment: @astentx works too, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about CTEs? Select `ID_TEAM_FK` first, use it to fetch `ID_LOCATION_FK`, insert the result.

```
INSERT INTO test (pk, id_team_fk, id_location_fk)
   WITH
      temp
      AS
      -- select random number from table
         (SELECT id_team_fk
            FROM (  SELECT id_team_FK
                      FROM team_table
                  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.random)
           WHERE ROWNUM = 1),
      temp2
      AS
      -- now you know ID_TEAM_FK (you fetched it in the TEMP CTE), so - fetch ID_LOCATION_FK
         (SELECT id_team_fk, id_location_fk
            FROM (SELECT a.id_team_fk, b.id_location_FK
                    FROM team_table a CROSS JOIN temp b
                   WHERE a.id_team_FK = b.id_team_FK))
   SELECT 1, id_team_fk, id_location_fk
     FROM temp2;
```